# what makes domain names point a specific folder?

Tags: apache, dns, httpd.conf

i'm working on a server that i inherited from someone, and i'm not a big expert on dns issues.
the server hosts more than one domains, and they are all under a folder called /vhosts/. 
i can't seem to understand how domains are pointing to their respective folder there. i checked httpd.config and there is no directive like this:

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

i also checked the domain admin and they are all pointing to the server ip. so what am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system could be configured for mass virtual hosting:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html

Alternately, the configurations for the virtual hosts could be declared in included files brought in through an Include statement.  Check the `httpd.config` for Include statements to other vhosts ...

if all else fails, go to the root of the configuration directory and run the following:

```
 sudo grep -Ri www.domain.tld .
```

Should give you a hint where to look ...

Answer (score 9):

`DocumentRoot` is the directive which tells the folder name for a specific hosted domain. For each domain which is hosted on the server, there will be one `<VirtualHost>` node in the `httpd.conf` file. So for example, example1.com and example2.com are hosted on this server and their requests are served from /vhosts/www/example1 and /vhosts/www/example2 respectively.

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot /vhosts/www/example1
ServerName www.example1.com
# Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot /vhosts/www/example2
ServerName www.example2.org
# Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Sometimes these settings are defined in other config files. Other config files are included in httpd.conf during startup. If you are unable to find the file that has it then I would suggest that you run

`grep -ri "VirtualHost" /`.

Comment: HOLY S***, this is what iam looking for, BIG THANKS MAtE! :B